# Where must PDB files be located for debugging to work?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Where must PDB files be located for debugging to work?

Comment: Have you tried to search the google for "PDB files" before posting the question? There are a lot of explaining articles.

Comment: Have you tried google? First post : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1(vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms241903(v=vs.90).aspx):

> A program database (PDB) file holds debugging and project state
>   information that allows incremental linking of a debug configuration
>   of your program. A PDB file is created when you build with /debug
>   (Visual Basic/C#). You can build Visual Basic and Visual C#
>   applications with /debug:full or /debug:pdbonly. Building with
>   /debug:full generates debuggable code. Building with /debug:pdbonly
>   generates PDBs but does not generate the DebuggableAttribute that
>   tells the JIT compiler that debug information is available. Use
>   /debug:pdbonly if you want to generate PDBs for a release build that
>   you do not want to be debuggable.

Also check this article by John Robbins: [PDB Files: What Every Developer Must Know](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know)